# How to get all the friends of the user in FB using iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

FaceBook launched new API from version 2.0 and asking users to upgrade to new SDK.
In my iOS application (which is not a game), user signs in using Facebook. In side the application I have an option to show all the FB friends of the user (friends who are not using the application).

I tried the below code which returns the friends who are using the application:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/friends"
                                 parameters:nil
                                 HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                          completionHandler:^(
                                              FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error
                                              ) {
                              /* handle the result */
                              NSLog(@"%@", result);
                          }];
```

And below code is not working in my application, because my app is not a game. As per FB, below code works only for Games.

```
FBRequest *request =  [FBRequest  requestWithGraphPath:@"me/invitable_friends"
                                                parameters:@{@"fields":@"name,installed,first_name"}
                                                HTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error){


        NSLog(@"%@", result);
    }];
```

Is there any other alternative to fetch the friends of the user?

Comment: nope, there is no way. invitable_friends is only for games and only for inviting users, and taggable_friends is only for tagging users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog), with the new Facebook Graph API 2.0, there is no way to fetch all friends.

> Friend list now only returns friends who also use your app: The list
>   of friends returned via the /me/friends endpoint is now limited to the
>   list of friends that have authorized your app

Comment: FBFriendPickerViewController available as part of iOS SDK is able to display all the friends of the logged in user. I don't know how FB is allowing it and stopped "me/Friends" to return all the friends list.